# How to prevent browser from closing connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I have a `node/express/react` project created with `create-react-app` and I can't figure out how to make the browser to not close the post requests that take longer than 2 minutes.

I'm using `Chrome` and it closes the post requests at exactly 2 minutes, sowing `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

I tried to set `res.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');` in the route, but doesn't work. Also tried with `req.setTimeout(0);` which works on all my other apps except on this `react-app`...

This is my route:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
      res.status(201).json({success: true});   
  }, 150000);
})

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3392) ... I solved same issue just today using `keepAliveTimeout` setting.